# Adding a UIView class outside ViewController class to show subview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

I have been check many close answers here, no one can solve my stupid problem..

My problem is: I have 2 classes, UIViewController classA and UIView classB.

A button(classA) trigger to process(classB), then show the subview on screen(classA).
But it doesn't work.

classA .m:

```
@implementation ViewController
...

- (IBAction)trigger:(UIButton *)sender {
    [classB  makeViewOn];
}
```

classB .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface classB : UIView
+ (void)makeViewOn;

@end
```

classB .m:

```
#import "classB.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation classB

+ (void)makeViewOn
{        
    ViewController *pointer = [ViewController new];
    UIWindow *window = pointer.view.window;

    classB *overlayView = [[classB alloc] initWithFrame:window.bounds];
    overlayView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
    overlayView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [pointer.view addSubview:overlayView];
}

@end
```

If I do this in only one class, UIViewController, it works fine; However, if I do this on two separate class(UIViewController & UIView), how can I fix it?

Am I doing something wrong on basic concepts of communicating between classes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the need of a separate UIView class?
Just declare a UIView inside your View controller and Hide it,
When the button is pressed, just unhide your view

Comment: Yes.. Actually I just don't want to put too much code in my ViewController instead of separating them into different classes. This way to keep me clear and easy to fix bug. haha.. anyway I'm still a beginner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**, you are creating a new object named **pointer** of class ViewController, therefore your classB object **overlayView** is not being added as a subview to the classA but rather to the object **pointer**.

**Secondly**, if you print and check your **window.bounds** its returning (null).

Modify you class method in classB

```
+ (void)makeViewOnParentView:(id)sender;

+ (void)makeViewOnParentView:(id)sender
{        
        ViewController *pointer = (ViewController*)sender;
        //UIWindow *window = pointer.view.window;
        CGRect rect=pointer.view.frame;

        classB *overlayView = [[classB alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
        overlayView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
        overlayView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [pointer.view addSubview:overlayView];
}
```

And in your classA call the method

```
[classB makeViewOnParentView:self];
```

Hope this will work for you...

Comment: It dose help me! I misunderstand using pointer, and lack the scene of sender idea. Now it seems the time to rewrite my project again! haha..
Really appreciate the answer and your time!